# is this query optimized?

Tags: sql-server, database, optimization, sql-server-2012

i got task to optimize the database, because this database has slow response.
is this possible, if i have around 90k records, if i want to select around 27k records, the responses time is 15s?
anything wrong with my query? or this is about indexes?

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;
SELECT workID AS pageID,
       projectName AS recProject,
       workType AS recType,
       workTitle AS recTitle,
       workDescription,
       workDate AS recDate,
       startTime,
       endTime,
       RTRIM(LTRIM(firstName + ' ' + lastName)) AS recName
FROM dbo.vTimesheets WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE isActiveProject = 1
    AND workType = 1
    AND timeFor = 2
ORDER BY recdate DESC, pageID DESC;
SET NOCOUNT OFF;
```

[image]

this query for view

```
SELECT dbo.tblTimesheet.workID,
       dbo.tblTimesheet.staffID,
       dbo.tblTimesheet.workDate,
       dbo.tblTimesheet.startTime,
       dbo.tblTimesheet.endTime,
       dbo.tblTimesheet.projectID,
       dbo.tblTimesheet.timeFor,
       dbo.tblTimesheet.workType,
       dbo.tblTimesheet.workTitle,
       dbo.tblTimesheet.workDescription,
       dbo.tblProject.projectName,
       dbo.tblProject.isDeleted AS isDeletedProject,
       dbo.tblProject.isActive AS isActiveProject,
       dbo.tblUser.firstName,
       dbo.tblUser.lastName,
       dbo.tblUser.isDeleted AS isDeletedStaff,
       dbo.tblUser.staffType
FROM dbo.tblTimesheet WITH (NOLOCK)
INNER JOIN dbo.tblUser WITH (NOLOCK) ON dbo.tblTimesheet.staffID = dbo.tblUser.userID
INNER JOIN dbo.tblProject WITH (NOLOCK) ON dbo.tblTimesheet.projectID = dbo.tblProject.projectID
WHERE (dbo.tblTimesheet.isDeleted = 0)
```

Comment: Check you execution plan what type scan it is using?

Comment: post your execution plan along with your question

Comment: How could we know if your indexes are ok or not if you don't include them?

Comment: sorry guys im new in sql server

Comment: So you're querying a view, please post the code for it too

Comment: @Jamesz: Good Catch, I had a thought of asking this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.tblTimesheet
    ADD workDescription2 AS CAST(workDescription AS VARCHAR(MAX)) 
GO

CREATE INDEX ix ON dbo.tblTimesheet (projectID, staffID, workDate DESC, workID DESC)
    INCLUDE (startTime, endTime, workType, workTitle, workDescription2, timeFor, isDeleted)
    WHERE isDeleted = 0 AND workType = 1 AND timeFor = 2
    --WITH (DROP_EXISTING=ON)

SELECT t.workID AS pageID,
       t.workDate AS recDate,
       t.startTime,
       t.endTime,
       t.workType AS recType,
       t.workTitle AS recTitle,
       t.workDescription2 AS workDescription,
       p.projectName AS recProject,
       RTRIM(LTRIM(u.firstName + ' ' + u.lastName)) AS recName
FROM dbo.tblTimesheet t --WITH (INDEX (ix))
JOIN dbo.tblUser u ON t.staffID = u.userID
JOIN dbo.tblProject p ON t.projectID = p.projectID
WHERE t.isDeleted = 0
    AND p.isActive = 1
    AND t.workType = 1
    AND t.timeFor = 2
ORDER BY t.workDate DESC, t.workID DESC
```

[image]

[this is the new execution plan](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwg77Cp4sokReE1ucUY2UndUSm8/view?usp=sharing)

but this slower than before

Comment: workDescription make it run slow. if i remove that it run faster.

Comment: http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2007/05/26/sql-server-2005-replace-text-with-varcharmax-stop-using-text-ntext-image-data-types/

Comment: is it possible if i use that varchar(max) if  i have more than 8000 character

Comment: Yes of course... also check about allocation units - `IN_ROW` and `LOB_DATA`. In your case main problem `LOB` column

Comment: hey, my PM dont want to change it to VARCHAR(MAX), he was afraid that data is truncated. what should i do if i want to make that query run faster than before

Comment: `VARCHAR(MAX) == TEXT` so I would be very surprised if you get truncated data. Just check info about why `TEXT` is a bad datatype...

Comment: About how to run faster... Please provide execution plan with my index and without

Comment: i cant create the index sir.. Column 'workDescription' in table 'dbo.tblTimesheet' is of a type that is invalid for use as included column in an index.

Comment: @hernawan adi saputro as you can see that `ix` index never used... Try to use hint `WITH (INDEX (ix))` and provide new execution plan (`*.sqlplan`)

Comment: @hernawan adi saputro my bad... Please modify your index (need add `projectID`, `staffID` to avoid `Lookup Key` operation)

Comment: I have done it. but the execution time didn't get better...Still slow like before the index(ix)

Comment: Sadly... But please note I don't have your environment. Only one thing that might be useful for me - actual execution plan saved as `sqlplan`

Comment: In common case, select for nonclust index a more preferable because we reducing logical reading

Comment: https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bwg77Cp4sokRNkxyZ1pwbHdfUkE/view?usp=sharing  .... this the sqlplan with index(ix) ... thank sir for helping me ^^

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE INDEX ix1 ON dbo.tblTimesheet (projectID, staffID, workID)
    INCLUDE (workType, timeFor, isDeleted)
    WHERE isDeleted = 0 AND workType = 1 AND timeFor = 2

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#temp') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #temp

CREATE TABLE #temp (
    workID INT PRIMARY KEY,
    recProject VARCHAR(50),
    recName VARCHAR(150)
)

INSERT INTO #temp (workID, recProject, recName)
SELECT t.workID,
       p.projectName,
       RTRIM(LTRIM(u.firstName + ' ' + u.lastName)) AS recName
FROM dbo.tblTimesheet t WITH (INDEX (ix1))
JOIN dbo.tblUser u ON t.staffID = u.userID
JOIN dbo.tblProject p ON t.projectID = p.projectID
WHERE t.isDeleted = 0
    AND p.isActive = 1
    AND t.workType = 1
    AND t.timeFor = 2

SELECT t.workID AS pageID,
       t.workDate AS recDate,
       t.startTime,
       t.endTime,
       1 AS recType,
       t.workTitle AS recTitle,
       t.workDescription,
       tt.recProject,
       tt.recName
FROM dbo.tblTimesheet t
JOIN #temp tt ON t.workID = tt.workID
ORDER BY t.workDate DESC, t.workID DESC
--OPTION(RECOMPILE)
```

Comment: Another idea... Fast select from nonclust index and after it join with clust index.

Comment: that workID is primary key... is that need to be index again?

Comment: Drop `ix` and computed column... and try this solution.

Comment: nothing changed sir... still same execution time... the workDescription have very much character (399721).. is that the problem?

Comment: Yes... I tried to avoid redundant reading from `PK`, but without results :(

Comment: `have very much character` ? please provide a small data sample. 
what you're trying to store in `workDescription`

Comment: nah, the problem is that.... i want to the workdescription with text datatype with that much character run faster :)... that workdescription has various datalength